# iPhone - Volume/Mute Buttons

Tags: iphone

What class is referenced in the volume/mute button popup?  Sorry for the awful question but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly by this pop-up... how do I get it to appear?

Comment: Hit your mute switch or change the volume.  It's also used in some apps to show activity or loading.

http://i48.tinypic.com/kc02n6.jpg
http://i49.tinypic.com/294hzjl.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a UIView with a semi transparent black backgroundColor. Then set the
`view.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;` (this will create rounded corners) and add whatever you would like to display within it to that view as non-opaque subviews with clear backgrounds.

You can then add the newly created view to your top-most view and set the frame to center nicely and add some animation.

You need to add the following line in the header-file:

```
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and also need add QuartzCore to your linked frameworks.

Comment: You could also make it a UIWindow subclass, if you want to make sure it displays on top of everything.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, this is not in the public API, and is not accessible by 'well-behaved' apps.

Comment: Weird, I have several apps installed that use something that looks exactly like it for a loading popup.

Comment: That was probably home-made, this is not something that comes out of the box in the iPhone SDK. You'll have to throw something together to mimic that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean UIAlertView? It's a blueish view which has text and (optionally) buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of MPVolumeSettingsAlertShow()?  That is a method to show the system volume alert.